# past perfect or past simple in this context

Tags: grammar

Is it good english

I thought you were going to take care of what I **said**?

Or shall I use past perfect

I thought you were going to take care of what I **had said** .

I think past perfect is not necessary here because it is obvious that what came first was the speech I made (but I am not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use "had said" if you wanted to indicate that what you said came before some other event. For example, you might have said A, then some other event happened, then you said B, and you want to make clear that you are talking about A and not B.

In many contexts, there'd be no difference in meaning.